# Port-forwarding for a minecraft server on 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, firewall, minecraft, port-forwarding

I've been trying to play with my friends online in Minecraft for a while now and the two methods I tried ended up failing.

The first method was to use hamachi, however its tunneling engines couldn't work and I have read that this is due to a firewall blocking it.

The second method I found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOjcJzNMW2M and it explains how to make your server but only you can join it. This is because you would need to use *port-forwarding* so that other people can join.

I know for a fact that **the port is 25565**, as it is the same for anyone trying to run a server in the method described in the video. Other than that I have no idea how to do this process. I know because of the hamachi problem that my firewall probably blocks this sort of thing too. So my question is: how do I run a Minecraft server with port-forwarding?

It is worth making clear that I already made a server through java that runs on my local address. If anyone has a step by step video that would help too, the only one I could find on YouTube was posted in 2013 and I worry that it is too dated to attempt.

Comment: I've run a Minecraft server for years. Multiple players can all connect on the same port 25565. A connection does not *block* the port. I've had up to six friends all playing remotely at once -- and only a single port forwarded.

Comment: I forwarded the 25565 port on my router. Is that all there is to it? Because one of my friends (the only one I've tried this with so far) could not join. Of course I forwarded the port only after opening the server. Could that be an issue or is my friend the one with the problem?